# How do I recover from a hung machine with an 'nfs server *** not responding' error?

Tags: freebsd, kill, nfs

```
nfs server *** not responding
nfs server *** not responding
nfs server *** not responding
nfs server *** not responding
nfs server *** not responding
nfs server *** not responding
```

I am getting this repeatedly and machine is hung. How can I stop that request?

I cannot initiate a new ssh connection also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `umount -f` to forcibly unmount. Depending on disk activity, it hasn't always worked for me; sometimes I've had to cycle the machine (unless I could restore the service).

For the future, you can look into whether `mount_nfs` arguments `-i` (interruptible), `-s` (soft mount), or `-R`*n* (maximum retry count) are appropriate for your environment.

I wasn't able to quickly tease out a gold standard for this, but here are some related items:

- [What are the advantages/disadvantages of hard versus soft mounts in UNIX?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9499/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-hard-versus-soft-mounts-in-unix) (recommends soft mounts for NFS)
- http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/NetAdminG/nfsD.nfsmount.html (recommends interruptible hard mounts for NFS)

Answer (score 2):

`umount -l /mnt/nfs` is very handy in situations like this as it will basically umount and ask questions later. What it does is *immediately* umount the file system, and leave any open files hangining. As it can it will kill off any open files to the dead nfs mount.

Comment: Also, be careful not to "tab" into the NFS mount when doing this as it will freeze!!

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is correct. I would add, that `lsof` is helpful to see what processes have files open on the NFS mount. I've always had to `kill -9` those pids and quickly `umount -f` immediately after. Sometimes it doesn't work and you have to reboot and reset.

Answer (score 0):

Getting to a point where you can manipulate fstab is important here.

You will need to boot the machine with a rescue disk, then edit the /etc/fstab to remove the line that is automounting the volume. Then you should be able to restart the machine and make appropriate changes mentioned by the other posters.

Comment: Sorry may have misread the question. I thought, for some reason, that the machine was hanging during boot. Sorry if it isn't.